# Websocket request succeeds in writing to DynamoDB but returns Internal Server Error

Tags: websocket, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

I created an AWS API Gateway route for Websocket connections.  I started with the AWS provided Simple Web Chat templates but have modified it to fit my needs.  The API Gateway calls a Lambda function that writes to a DynamoDB table.

I am able to make a websocket connection but when I make my next request to insert some data the data appears successfully in my DynamoDB table but the response I get back is Internal Server Error.

I don't understand what is causing the Internal Server Error.  When I look in the CloudWatch logs I just see normal traffic with no errors.

I could use some help understanding what is going wrong or how I can troubleshoot this better.

Here is the Lamba function that is being called:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const customId = require("custom-id");

const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
  apiVersion: "2012-08-10",
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
});

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const uniqueId = customId({
    randomLength: 1, 
  });

  const data = {
    uniqueId: uniqueId,
    members: [
      {
        connectionId: event.requestContext.connectionId,
      },
    ],
    events: [],
    parameters: [],
  };

  const putParams = {
    TableName: process.env.EVENT_TABLE_NAME,
    Item: data,
  };


  try {
    await ddb.put(putParams).promise();
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: "Failed to create: " + JSON.stringify(err),
    };
  }

  return { statusCode: 200, body: putParams };
};
```

[Image of AWS CloudWatch Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6vr4.png)

The error returned by wcat looks like this:
{"message": "Internal server error", "connectionId":"NZxV_ddNIAMCJrw=", "requestId":"NZxafGiyoAMFoAA="}

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem.  The issue in my case was because API Gateway did not have permission to call the Lambda function in order to process a message arriving from the websocket.  The 'internal server error' in this case is API Gateway saying it had some problem when it tried to invoke the Lambda function to handle the websocket message.

I was using CDK to deploy the infrastructure, and I created one `WebSocketLambdaIntegration` for the connect, disconnect and default websocket handlers, but this doesn't work.  You have to create separate `WebSocketLambdaIntegration` instances even if you are calling the same Lambda function for all websocket events, otherwise CDK does not set the correct permissions.

I could see this was the problem because 1) I was using the same Lambda function for the connect, disconnect and default routes, and 2) in CloudWatch Logs I was only seeing log messages for one of these routes, in this case the 'connect' one.  When I sent a message over the websocket, I was not seeing the expected log messages from the Lambda that was supposed to be handling incoming websocket messages.  When I disconnected from the websocket, I did not see the expected log messages from the 'disconnect' handler.

This was because CDK had only given Lambda invoke permission to specific routes on the API Gateway websocket stage, and it had only authorised the 'connect' route, not the others.

Fixing the CDK stack so that it correctly assigned permissions, allowing API Gateway to invoke my Lambda for all websocket routes, fixed the problem.

Comment: Hours of debugging until this saved me! Filed a report and the bug can be tracked here: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/21080

Answer (score 1):

I see it now.  It was the last line.  I changed it and now it works fine.

```
return { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify(putParams) };
```